# App Engine: prefetch_refprops-like function for resolving lists of keys

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

When dealing with ReferenceProperties I often make use a function called `prefetch_reprops` to efficiently resolve references. However, I am currently dealing with a model that makes use of a list of `db.Key` instances.

Does anyone have a `prefetch_refprops`-like function for dealing with lists of keys?

[Here is a better explanation of prefetch_refprops](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/01/ReferenceProperty-prefetching-in-App-Engine)

Comment: I'm not sure why you need a prefetch method for the list of keys.  db.get() accepts a list of keys and db.put() accepts a list of entities.

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/functions.html

Answer (score 0):

Just call `db.get` on the list of keys, exactly as the `prefetch_refprops` function does.